# cannot understand this piece of c++ code

Tags: c++

I am reading some c++ open source code and a beginner in c++, I found this piece of code is very hard to understand, I don't know what this code are doing and why should it be written in this way. Could any body give me any clue? (The question part is on `rndseq[k] = (rndseq[k] << 8) | (rand() & 0xff)`;)

```
 static unsigned int rndseq[2048];
    for (k = 0; k < 2048; k++)
    {
                rndseq[k] = 0;
                for (i=0; i < (int)sizeof(int); ++i)
                    rndseq[k] = (rndseq[k] << 8) | (rand() & 0xff);
    }
```

Comment: thats C not C++. You are looking for the word "bitshift" btw.

Comment: You can easily search for these operators on the internet. There is no need to ask such question.

Comment: okey, I saw your quality. No need for further discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(rndseq[k] << 8) | (rand() & 0xff)
```

these are binary-operation, (see bit-operations in C)

it can be translated into

```
rndseq[k] * 256 + rand() % 256
```

the idea behind the code is, to create a large array with random entries, but its way too complicated

i hope, this helps you to understand the logic

```
    //we want to fill this array with random numbers
    static unsigned int rndseq[2048];
    // for each k-entry of the array
    for (k = 0; k < 2048; k++)
    {
                // initialize k-entry with zero
                rndseq[k] = 0;
                // for each byte in the k-entry integer
                for (i=0; i < (int)sizeof(int); ++i)
                    //on the first iteration rndseq[k] is zero, so  
                    //(rndseq[k] << 8) remains zero. 
                    //(rand() & 0xff) creates a random number in the range [0,255]
                    //-> in the first iteration rndseq[k] will be set to a random number ([0,255])
                    //lets say, you have a int32 (4 bytes)
                    //you need 1 byte to represent 255
                    //so you have 3 "empty" bytes and 1 filled
                    //lets say, rand() got the number 1
                    //than rndseq would have the following value
                    //0x00-0x00-0x00-0x01

                    //in the next iteration you shift 1 byte, so 
                    //you get from (rndseq[k] << 8)
                    //0x00-0x00-0x01-0x00
                    //the next random-number (still 1 byte) (lets say 2)
                    //will be stored in now free last byte
                    //result:
                    //0x00-0x00-0x01-0x02
                    //now you repeat, until all bytes are set
                    //result:
                    //0x01-0x02-0x03-0x04
                    rndseq[k] = (rndseq[k] << 8) | (rand() & 0xff);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been so helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the point!
I think the key idea behind the code is, we are not sure how many bits are there in `rndseq[k]` and `rand()`, so the code fill every 8 bits in rndseq[k] with a random. 
`rand() & 0xff` means get the last 8 bits of the random number, then use the operate "|" to fill these 8 bits into the last 8 bits in `rndseq[k]` (the previous filled 8 bits have been kept by <<8 ). The for loop is used for fill every 8 bits in `rndseq[k]` with a random.